# How to say a fireplace is "on"

Tags: word-usage

I know you can use the following sentence to describe it like this:

> The wood was burning in the fireplace.

But does there exist a single adjective that could replace "on" in this sentence:

> The fireplace was on.

I'm thinking it could be replaced with "lit":

> The firelace was lit.

Any other, better suggestions?

Comment: _Lit_ was my first thought, and I suspect that it's going to be the best choice.

Comment: Maybe "burning"?

Comment: No, the _wood_ is burning, not the _fireplace_.

Comment: I wouldn't say it was "lit", because that's slang for "intense". Besides, are you really lighting the entire fireplace?

Comment: @FeliniusRex - one says that a lamp is lit, or that a candelabrum is lit, even though it's only the bulb or the candle(s) that are actually lit. As far as _lit_ ≅ _intense_, that usage is _far_ less common in my experience.

Comment: A fire burns in a fireplace. The fireplace is not the fire.

Comment: *scratching head* I said that because it's pretty common in my experience to say things are "lit". When you light a fire, you don't light a fireplace.

Comment: Besides all that, there are different kinds of fireplaces. A gas fireplace can be **on**, but produce no flame. An electric fireplace generates flames/heat soon after being turned **on**.

Comment: @FeliniusRex - where I come from, we have _gas fires_ and _electric fires_. These can be 'on' or 'off'. A fireplace is a kind of hole in the wall with a chimney above, lined with fireproof bricks, and often with a arrangement around it called a 'mantel', and possibly a tiled floor level 'kerb'. Fireplaces used to have an iron grate that held burning coal or wood, and often you find a gas or electric fire fitted in place of that. Of course most UK homes have a boiler and radiators these days.

Comment: If a fireplace is lit, it means that there is a light shining on/in it. If a fire is lit, it means that the fire (which has been prepared) has been set alight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don’t often light fires nowadays and the everyday words describing the process are being forgotten.

For example:

> K. L. **set alight to** 72-year-old J.C. in her
> garden [...], on 13 March 2018 before killing himself.
> [bbc.co.uk/news]
>
> A man has been injured after the car he was in **went on fire** on an
> unclassified road between Dingwall and Evanton. [bbc.co.uk/news]
>
> You look at me and, babe, I wanna **catch on fire** [Lady Gaga: *Always
> Remember Us This Way*]
>
> Three people were onboard when it came down, hitting power lines and
> **setting alight** on the A14 near Abergavenny. [BBC TV Ten O’Clock News]
>
> They tore down a giant banner celebrating communist China's 70th
> anniversary and rapidly **put it to flame**. [BBC TV Ten O’Clock News]
>
> ...**to light on fire** [ChronicleLive.co.uk]

You can light a fire.
You can **set light to** something, **set fire to** something, **set something alight** and **set something on fire**.
You can’t set alight to something. Nothing can set alight.
Things **catch fire**. (In some dialects you might wait, say, for the wood to catch.)
Once they have caught fire, things are **on fire**. But they don’t go on fire or catch on fire or light on fire.

While "put to the sword" appears in print occasionally, "put to flame" and "put to the flame" make very rare appearances: mostly in the writings of Lord of the Rings fans.

Answer (score 1):

There is the word ***alight*** which means *burning* ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/alight))

The [FreeDictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/alight) defines it as meaning

> Burning; lighted:
>
> - The discarded match was still ***alight***.

There is also ***[aflame](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/aflame)*** but it is literary, and ***[ablaze](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ablaze)***, but this means *burning very strongly*, so it may be too intense.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture of a fireplace. In it, a fire is burning. The fire is lit (or burning). The fireplace does not burn.

[image]